# Can not access variables in templates

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I am facing some issue with the template in ansible. I am not able to access ansible variables in templates defined in files. This is my template code:

```
{% for count in range(1,{{ total_count }}) %}
  - tmp_{{ build_type }}_{{ count }}
{% endfor %}
```

`total_count` and `build_type` is defined in files which are included in the ansible playbook.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Then there must be something wrong in how you include these vars files. If a var is defined, you can directly access it in any template. There is pretty much nothing you can do wrong other then typos.

Comment: Now looking at your code: Are your sure the vars are not available? You get any error? Please try this: `{% for count in range(1, total_count) %}`

Comment: I have created variables in file /etc/ansible/vars/myVariables.yml and included this file using vars_file in playbook. If I use the syntax mentioned by udondan I am getting blank line in final file.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed. I was running the range(1,1) and that's why it was not working. I tried for range(1,2) and it worked fine.

Thanks,
Sanjiv